# How to parse a mixed CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I am dealing with a CSV file similar to this one

```
foo; val1; position1
bar; name1; address1; phone_nbr1
bar; name2; address2; phone_nbr2
foo; val2; position2
bar; name3; address3; phone_nbr3
bar; name4; address4; phone_nbr4
bar; name5; address5; phone_nbr5
bar; name6; address6; phone_nbr6
foo; val3; position3
```

Needless to say, I cannot modify the CSV.

Instances displayed in `foo` lines are different from the ones with `bar` lines (notice they don't even have the same number of fields)

I need simply reading this data, no need to write it.

My first idea was to separate the file into two temporary files and then read each one separately with a `csv.DictReader`, however I really don't like this approach.

Is there a simpler way to do this? I would like to avoid if possible having to write files to disk.

For the record, I'm using Python2.7 on a Solaris 10 machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could collect the records from a `csv.reader` in two different lists, depending on their length (or whatever criterion you use to distinguish the two streams):

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
with open("input.csv", "rb") as f:
    for record in csv.reader(f, delimiter=";"):
        if len(record) == 3:
            list1.append(record)
        else:
            list2.append(record)
```

Answer (score 4):

`csv.reader()` has no problem with this:

```
import csv
foo = []
bar = []
with open("test.csv", 'r') as f:
    c = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ";")
    for row in c:
        if row[0] == "foo":
            foo.append(row[1:])
        elif row[0] == "bar":
            bar.append(row[1:])
print(foo)
print(bar)
```

results in

```
[[' val1', ' position1'], [' val2', ' position2'], [' val3', ' position3']]
[[' name1', ' address1', ' phone_nbr1'], [' name2', ' address2', ' phone_nbr2'], [' name3', ' address3', ' phone_nbr3'], [' name4', ' address4', ' phone_nbr4'], [' name5', ' address5', ' phone_nbr5'], [' name6', ' address6', ' phone_nbr6']]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just using [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on each line?

```
items = line.split(";")
```

Then if the first item in the `items` list is `foo` you do one thing, and if it's `bar` you do something else.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the lines are different is not a problem for `csv` module, but you'll have to analyze line content differently depending on first 'cell'.

Example of code:

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as fin:
    c = csv.reader(fin)
    for line in c:
         if line[0] == 'foo':
              # do some treatment
         elif line[0] == 'bar':
              # do something else
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what it is you actually want to achieve, but I'm not sure you need the csv module here.

```
for row in myfile.readlines():
    cols = [r.strip() for r in row.split(';')]
    if (cols[0] == "foo"):
        # Do something for foo
    elif (cols[0] == "bar"):
        # Do something for bar
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
foos = []
bars = []
for line in csv.reader(open("file.csv","rb"), delimiter=";"):
  if line[0] == "foo":
    foos.append(Foo(line[1], line[2]))
  else:
    bars.append(Bar(line[1], line[2], line[3]))
```

Assuming you have a `Foo` and a `Bar` class taking the rest of your line cells as arguments.